# C++ Function overloading using const parameters

Tags: c++, constants

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class CheckConst
{
public:
    void func(int* p)
    {
        cout << "func called";
    }

    void func(const int* p)
    {
        cout << "const func called";
    }
};

int main()
{
    int* p = nullptr;
    CheckConst obj;
    obj.func(p);
}
```

Above function overloading works fine. But why is the complier not complaining, both the function overloads are valid for function call for obj.func(p). If I remove either one of the function from the class, the code still works.

How is the complier distinguishing which one to call?

Comment: The type of `p` is `int*`, so the compiler prefers to match that. If no method matching `int*` is available, then the compiler will match the `const int*` method. If, on the other hand, you make `p` a `const int*`, and you remove `func(const int*)` this will result in a compiler error.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that.
So, this  works due to compilation rules related to const function overloading ?

Comment: Neither of these are "const functions". The matching is part of [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution). In particular, see [ranking of implicit conversion sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences)

Comment: The second function requires a qualification conversion but the first doesn't. So the second is worse match than the first. Basically, the first function is an **exact match**.

Comment: The class here is a distraction. `void f(int*) ...` and `void f(const int*) ...` as global functions would do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why is the complier not complaining

Because the first function `func(int* p)` is an **exact match** via *identity conversion* while the second function `func(const int* p)` requires a **qualification conversion**(aka conversion to const).

Thus, second function is **worst match** than the first, for the argument `p`.

---

Basically, the first function doesn't require any conversion(aka identity conversion) for its argument `p`.

From [over.ics.rank](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank#3.2):

> **Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2** if
>
> - **S1 and S2 differ only in their qualification conversion** ([conv.qual]) and yield similar types T1 and T2, respectively, where T1 can be converted to T2 by a qualification conversion.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler picks the func overload with the least required argument conversion. For `int* p = nullptr;`, it chooses `func(int*)` because it's a direct match without conversion. Since nullptr is valid for both `int*` and `const int*`, removing either overload still leads to unambiguous function selection.

The key to understanding how the compiler makes its choice lies in the type of the argument p and the concept of "qualification conversion."  In the context of function overloading, C++ prefers to match functions with the least amount of conversion required for the arguments.